# Reduce Image Width Without Resizing (e.g. crop image dynamically)

Tags: javascript, css

The best way for me to explain my problem is to basically just give you this link:

http://www.tarmac.co.uk/default.aspx?landing=false

On this web page there a some kind of Javascript slideshow with a twist. The images are crammed into the box, but they are not resized, just overlapping. On hover, the images return to their original size, then shrink back.

I was wondering how this is possible?

I thought of the whole "position: relative" malarky but im not sure if this is the way forward.

So I tried to make it, I used "float: left" and "display: inline" to line images up, but then they wrap over.

I also tried "width: auto" but I feel that... I just cant see how to do it?

If anyone can link to a tutorial that would be better, but I couldn't find any!

Cheers,

Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the page you provided images just lying into the `li` and the `width` property of `li` changes on hover.

So I think, you have to put image into the some container and modify container's width.

Try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L3sCC/

Comment: I thought as much. I probably didnt make my predicament clear enough. When you change the width of the image in the css, it resizes the image. Whereas I dont want to resize, just hide some of it. I understand i could use "position: relative;" and shuffle the latter pictures over the previous images, but when you use position relative, the space is still used for the natural position of the image, and the image itself is just moved. I'm really struggling explaining exactly what I mean! Thanks for the reply anyway:)

Comment: Check out the fiddle I've attached, i think it would give you an idea